# Preparing simple query for PDO connection

Tags: mysql, json, pdo

I would like to prepare PDO statement and convert results to JSON in PHP. I managed to connect to database by following method:

```
class DB_CONNECT {

function __construct() {
    $this->connect();
}

function __destruct() {
    $this->close();
}

function connect() {
    $root = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT"); 
    require_once ($root.'/db/db_config.php');

    try
    {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_SERVER.';dbname='.DB_DATABASE.';charset=utf8;port='.DB_PORT, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo 'OK';
        return $db;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        print "Connection error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }

}

function close() {

    $db = null;
}
```

PHP, where I make statements looks like this:

```
$root = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT"); 
require_once ($root.'/db/db_connect.php');

$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$statement=$db->prepare("SELECT name, surname FROM lecturer");
$statement->execute();
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($results);
```

When I run this PHP, I'm getting only OK message, that the connection went successfully. What's wrong with that query code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your error log say? From your code, I can tell you that `$db` doesn't contain a `PDO` object, as you don't return anything in the constructor of `DB_CONNECT`. So `$db` is an object of type `DB_CONNECT`, not of type `PDO`, and thus doesn't have `prepare` as a method.

For a quick fix, change

```
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
```

to

```
$db = DB_CONNECT::connect();
```

and make `connect` static.